# Completely undo changes made in TortoiseSVN and commit latest file

Tags: tortoisesvn

I created folders in TortoiseSVN's repo browser. Then I copied all files in it. Then I wanted to delete all files from previous folders. But I couldn't because those files were already locked by someone else.

I want to completely undo the changes I made today and commit those changes and start working fresh. I tried using update to version but it only updates the working copy and does not commit it because no changes are made.

How can I completely undo changes made in TortoiseSVN and commit latest file

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a [reverse merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo) of the changes and commit that. Then copy your "latest" version in and commit that.